# solution to a complex equation

Tags: complex-numbers

I'm asked to solve this equation :
$$z^4+7(1+i)z^2+25i=0$$
by taking $z^2 = u $ :
$$u^2+7(1+i)u+25i=0$$
this turns out to be a quadratic equation. solving it gives:
$$u_1=-6-8i$$
$$u_2=-8-6i$$
so how are we supposed to solve $z^2=-6-8i$ and $z^2=-8-6i$ ?
answeres are :
$$z=\pm \sqrt5(sin\beta/2-icos\beta/2)$$
$$z=\pm \sqrt5(sin\alpha/2-icos\alpha/2)$$
where $\alpha = Arctan(4/3)$ and $\beta = Arctan(3/4)$
I have no idea how to get this answers.

Comment: Put $u_1$ and $u_2$ in polar form then use DeMoivre's Theorem for the roots

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$z^4+7(1+i)z^2+25i=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$z^4+(7+7i)z^2+25i=0\Longleftrightarrow$$

---

Substitute $x=z^2$:

---

$$x^2+(7+7i)x+25i=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$(x+(3+4i))(x+(4+3i))=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$x+(3+4i)=0\Longleftrightarrow\space\space\vee\space\space x+(4+3i)=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$x=-3-4i\Longleftrightarrow\space\space\vee\space\space x=-4-3i\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$z^2=-3-4i\Longleftrightarrow\space\space\vee\space\space z^2=-4-3i\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$z^2=|-3-4i|e^{\arg(-3-4i)i}\Longleftrightarrow\space\space\vee\space\space z^2=|-4-3i|e^{\arg(-4-3i)i}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$z^2=5e^{\left(\arctan\left(\frac{4}{3}\right)-\pi\right)i}\Longleftrightarrow\space\space\vee\space\space z^2=5e^{\left(\arctan\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)-\pi\right)i}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$z=\left(5e^{\left(\arctan\left(\frac{4}{3}\right)-\pi+2\pi k\right)i}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\Longleftrightarrow\space\space\vee\space\space z=\left(5e^{\left(\arctan\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)-\pi+2\pi l\right)i}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$z=\sqrt{5}e^{\frac{1}{2}\left(\arctan\left(\frac{4}{3}\right)-\pi+2\pi k\right)i}\space\space\vee\space\space z=\sqrt{5}e^{\frac{1}{2}\left(\arctan\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)-\pi+2\pi l\right)i}$$

With $k,l\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $k,l:0-1$

---

So the solutions are:

$$z_0=\sqrt{5}e^{\frac{1}{2}\left(\arctan\left(\frac{4}{3}\right)-\pi+2\pi \cdot 0\right)i}=1-2i$$
$$z_1=\sqrt{5}e^{\frac{1}{2}\left(\arctan\left(\frac{4}{3}\right)-\pi+2\pi \cdot 1\right)i}=-1+2i$$
$$z_2=\sqrt{5}e^{\frac{1}{2}\left(\arctan\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)-\pi+2\pi \cdot 0\right)i}=\sqrt{-4-3i}$$
$$z_3=\sqrt{5}e^{\frac{1}{2}\left(\arctan\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)-\pi+2\pi \cdot 1\right)i}=-\sqrt{-4-3i}$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
$$
u^2+(7-7i)u+25i=(u+3+4i)(u+4+3i)
$$
so you have some mistake in your solutions.

Write the solutions in polar form:

$$
u_1=-3-4i=5e^{i\theta_1} \quad with \quad \theta_1=\arctan \frac{4}{3}
$$
 $$
u_2=-4-3i=5e^{i\theta_1} \quad with \quad \theta_2=\arctan \frac{3}{4}
$$
 now you can do ?